# Is narrowing the return type a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, binary-compatibility

Let's say I have a .NET library (v1.0) with the following method:

```
public IPrincipal GetUser() { ... }
```

and in version 2.0 I replace it with

```
public MyUserClass GetUser() { ... }
```

to provide newer clients with additional information.

**Assuming that `MyUserClass` implements `IPrincipal`, is this a breaking change?**

By "breaking change" I mean "breaking w.r.t. **binary compatibility**": If `SomeClient.exe` uses v1.0 of `myLibrary.dll`, and I replace it with v2.0 without recompiling `SomeClient.exe`, will I get into trouble? (Source code compatibility is obviously satisfied. In addition, I am not using strong named assemblies.)

Comment: How can it *not* break?  `SomeClient.Exe` v1.0 has no idea what `MyUserClass` is, even if it does know what `IPrincipal` is :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: `SomeClient.exe` does not *need* to know what `MyUserClass` is: `IPrincipal myUser = GetUser()` is a valid statement in both cases.

Comment: Is MyUserClass already present in v1.0 ?

Comment: @Thilo: No. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Heinzi, I believe it does.  If your `GetUser()` function still returned an `IPrincipal` (even if it was actually a `MyUserClass` than that might be different.

Comment: Wouldn't the caller need to know `MyUserClass` regardless of if it's used because it's a publicly exposed type?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth no if it's not used but in this case function signature has been changed then SomeClient won't find the method it's looking for.

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks for digging up the duplicate, I probably missed it while googling because it did not include the word "narrow". Voting to close. :-)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, if someone returned YourUserClass (which also implemented IPrincipal), it will no longer work.</strike>

Comment: Not really because GetUser() is not virtual so it'll return what it wants. Of course it may be more tricky if it calls a virtual method to get IPrincipal (but it's not the point of the question)